# About proof for a point inside a closed set

Tags: general-topology

I wonder whether one can just use definition of the closed set to prove the following statement without resorting upon taking contrapositive or proof by contradiction. 
Let A be a subset of topological space. A point x is in closure of A , if and only if every open set U containing x intersects A. Is there a direct proof without using contrapositive statement or proof by contradiction?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x \in \bar A$.  Let $U$ be an open set containing $x$.  Then $\bar A \setminus U$ is a closed set with $(\bar A \setminus U) \subsetneq \bar A$.  Since $\bar A$ is defined to be the smallest closed set containing $A$, we cannot have $A \subset (\bar A \setminus U)$.  We may thereby conclude that $A \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Thus, every open set containing $x$ intersects $A$.

Now, suppose that that every open set containing $x$ intersects $A$.  We note that since $\bar A$ is closed, $(\bar A)^c$ is open. $(\bar A)^c$ is an open set that does not intersect $A$, so $A^c$ does not contain $x$, by the problem's assumption.

Since $x \notin (\bar A)^c$, $x \in \bar A$.

Of course, all this is made much clearer with a proof by contraposition/contradiction.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is not to use proof by contradiction or contrapositive statement for proof. Here you used proof by contradiction. I want a proof by just using the plain definition of closed set.

Comment: What is "the plain definition of a closed set" if not "$A$ is closed if $A^c$ is open"?

Comment: Is this any better?

Comment: I have not seen a proof with using sole the definition of a set is closed if its complement is open. So I am wondering whether it can be done by just using definition without any tricks.

Comment: What trick have I used here?

Comment: Sorry, I typed something wrong. I was intending to say the closure of A not A. Here A may not be open. Sorry for the confusion.